Use of multiple comparison correction and composite DV
I am investigating the effect of a single X on a composite DV, Y. I want to also investigate the effect of X on the 36 sub-components of Y. Thus, I would have to run 37 multiple regression models, specifically pooled OLS with robust clustered SEs and year FEs. X is time-invariant so I cannot include country FEs.
I understand that I should correct for multiple comparison, and I intend to use BH correction. My question is that should I adjust for all models, including the main model where composite Y is the DV? To be clear, this is a conditional process: only if X is significant in the main model would it be tested against the sub-components.
I am stumped because I did adjust the p-values for the main model, but X in the main model was not significant after correction. Yet, X is significant for a good number of the sub-components. I know it's bad science to question the model on seeing unfavourable results, but I am struggling to interpret the results if X's initial significant effect in the main model is attributable to noise.
To sum up, I have two questions:

If I have a conditional process, where more models will be run only if X has a significant effect in the main model, does the p-value of the main model need to be adjusted for multiple comparison? If I have a conditional process, are the tests still considered simultaneous?
If adjustment is required, how do I resolve the paradox where adjustment is needed because the initial effect was significant, but then the initial effect becomes non-significant after adjustment, hence negating the need for further tests and consequently adjustment?

